# LiveData observer is not removed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, observer-pattern, observers

I am trying to get `LiveData` updates in a `ViewModel`, and make sure that the observer is not leaking, but it is leaking. The typical problem is that the observer is not stored in a variable, but that is not the case here; the lambda is stored in a variable.

```kotlin
    private val observer: (List<MusicFile>) -> Unit =
        { musicFiles: List<MusicFile> ->
            _uiState.postValue(FragmentMusicListState(musicFiles))
        }

    init {
        musicRepository.musicFiles.observeForever(observer)
    }

    @VisibleForTesting(otherwise = VisibleForTesting.PROTECTED)
    public override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        musicRepository.musicFiles.removeObserver(observer)
    }
```

The problem is that after onCleared is called, the observer is still attached. I verified this with the following test.

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun onCleared_RemovesObserver() {
        val musicRepository = MusicRepository.getInstance()
        val context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext
        musicRepository.loadMusicFiles(context.contentResolver)
        val musicFiles = musicRepository.musicFiles
        val viewModel = FragmentMusicListViewModel(SavedStateHandle(), musicRepository)

        viewModel.onCleared()
        assert(!musicFiles.hasObservers())
    }
```

In addition, I have debugged the test on the last line, and musicFile's attributes show the observer is still attached. Attributes mActiveCount and mObservers show the observer is still attached,

How do I actually remove the observer?

Comment: Hi! Please edit your question to include a tag for the language, it makes it easier for people to help, thank you and happy new year!

Comment: My bad; updated

Comment: This is always the wrong way to approach the problem (you shouldn't be observing data in your ViewModel at all) - you should be using a [transformation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#transform_livedata) - in this case, it looks like a simple `map`.

Comment: Thank you for that! If you write an answer I can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LiveData takes an argument of type `Observer<T>` in observeForever and removeObserver. Observer is what Kotlin considers a **[functional interface](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/fun-interfaces.html)** written in Java in the androidx.lifecycle library.

What you are passing in is of type `(List<MusicFile>) -> Unit`.

This is a high order function and is not the same type as `Observer<List<MusicFile>>`. They are functionally similar in that they both have one parameter of type `List<MusicFile>` and both return `Unit`, so what Kotlin does for the better or for the worse (the worse in this case) is it will "cast" the type for you.

When Kotlin "casts" from high-order function to functional interface it is creating a new object. This happens every single time in your code when either observeForever or removeObserver are called. That's why removeObserver isn't working, because you're actually not passing in the same object despite how the code looks. [I've written about this before.](https://trevorhackman.medium.com/avoid-this-bug-in-kotlin-b668fb6fc94e)

In short, you can fix your problem by changing the type of observer to Observer:

```
private val observer: Observer<List<MusicFile>> =
    Observer { musicFiles: List<MusicFile> ->
        // _uiState.postValue(FragmentMusicListState(musicFiles))
    }
```